# When inserted my external HDD all external HDD and flashdrive doesn't detected

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have this weird problem, whenever I inserted my external HDD it will not show in BIOS, device management and even in my computer. It becomes weird becomes when I inserted it it will make other externals not functioning, this includes my pocket wifi that is inserted to my desktop, other external HDD and also flashdrive, it also prevents my windows 7 from restarting and shutting down, even when opening it, but once I removed the external HDD my computer becomes normal again.

Comment: **Sounds like the device is defective.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'ts been a long time, and unfortunately my device is defective. There is nothing that I can do about it, I even asked experts and they said there's not much they can do about it.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that your HDD has a hardware malfunction, you'll need to test it against another computer.

But I've also seen that behaviour happen if you're connecting it through a USB 3.0 port. Try a legacy 2.0 port even if your HDD is 3.0 compatible. You'll recognize the 2.0 ports because they are black, the 3.0 ones are blue.